# Java - Array Issues

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, jframe

Issue: Code although works, doesn't give proper results.

Code as follows:

```java
private void AddButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:        
        int i = Integer.parseInt(input.getText());
        int n = 0;
        int [] array;
        
        array = new int[5];
        

        if (n < array.length) {
            array[n] = i;
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
            System.out.println(array.length);
            n++; 
        } else {
            output.setText("Test.");
            input.setText("");
        }
        
    }
```

Results as follows:

```java
[5, 0, 0, 0, 0]
5
```

Expected result:
First array full, head to second, repeat until 5th.

Any help is appreciated.

[image: java jFrame photo]

Attempts in changes:

- Changes in if statement, originally had different values. Changed to hopefully make work.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by _Expected result: First array full, head to second, repeat until 5th._  Can you clarify with what the code should output (similar to the actual output)?

Comment: Let's say we have an array, with following lines: [a, b, c, d, e].
a, b, c, d, e are all values.

If a is occupied, we head to b, repeat process until we reached e, then send out an message in output [ the long textfield in photo. ]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that I followed you right, but looks like you need to move `array` and `n` outside of the method, in order to preserve the state between button clicks. Something like this:

```
// Inside class
private int n = 0;
private int[] array = new int[5];

private void AddButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    int i = Integer.parseInt(input.getText());        

    if (n < array.length) {
        array[n] = i;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        System.out.println(array.length);
        n++; 
    } else {
        output.setText("Test.");
        input.setText("");
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Not really what I wanted, but, appreciate the help.

Mainly what I am trying to focus on is the **if statement**, everything else works perfectly fine.

Comment: Actually, this answer IS exactly what you need.

Comment: How so?
Please tell me, I would actually love to know.

Comment: In the version in your question, no state is preserved between button clicks.